# Why can't I see links to custom file uploads when viewing an activity record?

Tags: custom-fields, activities

Running version 4.7.6 (but this has been the case for us for some time now):

We are using activities in cases to upload a range of documentation for a given case that we are working on. The uploads work fine.

But if I view an activity to which files have been uploaded I can't see (or click) on the links to the files. However, if I edit the activity record I can see and use the links.

I can't replicate this issue on the demo site (which looks to be running 4.7.7 as I write this).

Is anyone seeing the same issue, or is it something to do with my specific install? Any ideas as to how I might address this?

Comment: Do the affected users have a role with the permission 'access uploaded files'?

Comment: Right now I'm seeing the issue logged in as user 1. However, the users who will need to see and access these files do have this permission.